# Jquery Append Hover css styles

Tags: jquery, css

I want to append some hover css styles to some buttons using jQuery, I currently have it so it adds the css I want but when your not hovering the button the styles stay.

heres my code:

```
                $('#all').hover(function() {
                    $('#all').css({backgroundColor: '#3DC0F1', color: '#ffffff'});
                })
```

When you hover it adds those styles but when you move the mouse off hover it keeps the styles, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just use pure CSS for this: http://jsfiddle.net/JDX5Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please use following:

```
mouseenter()
.mouseleave()

.mouseover()
.mouseout()
```

Or try below code

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67tCr/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS like that :

```
 #all:hover {
    backgroundColor:#3DC0F1;
    color: #ffffff
   }
```

Comment: Hi, I do have that set but because I'm using jQuery to set other css styles it seems to now allow my css hover states

Comment: Ok if you want to do this in jquery only then use @Mohit Arora answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#all').hover(function() {
                $('#all').css({backgroundColor: '#3DC0F1', color: '#ffffff'});
      },function(){
              //remove style here
           $('#all').removeAttr("style");
 });
```

Demo:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JGeLz/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this like:

HTML:

```
<button class="all">a</button>
<button class="all">b</button>
<button class="all">c</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.all').hover(function() {
                    $('.all').css({backgroundColor: '#3DC0F1', color: '#ffffff'});
                });
    $('.all').mouseout(function() {
                    $('.all').removeAttr('style');
                });
});
```

and I advice to use `class` instead of `id`.